# How to validate a data insert with mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

how can i validate after data insert and saving data to database if data already in a database send user to error alert message.
how can i do this with express REST server?

this is my "POST" on client side

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

            var service_ = service.value;
            var amount_ = amount.value;
            var name_ = name.value;
            var phone_ = phone.value;
            var reminder_ = reminder.value;

            if (start_pick < end_pick) {
                var jsondata = [{
                    start_time : new Date(start_pick),
                    end_time : new Date(end_pick),
                    service : service_,
                    amount : amount_,
                    client_phone : phone_,
                    client_name : name_,
                    reminder : reminder_
                }];

                var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
                xhr.setTimeout(10000);

                xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/collections/appoinments");
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
                xhr.onerror = function() {

                    Titanium.API.info("Error in connecting to server !!");
                    alert("Error on connecting to server, Please try again");
                };
                 xhr.onload = function() {

                windowPayment.close();

        }
```

this is my POST on server

```
    app.post('/collections/:collectionName', function(req, res, next) {
  req.collection.insert(req.body, {}, function(e, results){
    if (e) return next(e)
    res.send(results)
  })
})
```

how can i do this.any help?

Comment: add a `..collection.find()...` method before inserting to check if the user already exists.

Comment: @ravi please can you give  some more code.im really new to this.

Comment: what is the primary/unique field in that data?

Comment: @ravi start_time and end_time

Comment: You're generating `start_time` and `end_time` dynamically, so they will always be different. While using `find()` method of mongo, you need to specify a key: value that would check if that record already exists or not.

Comment: @ravi this start_time and end_time given by user.so how can i write in `find()` method ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64166/discussion-between-ravi-and-sameera).

Comment: @ravi want i add some client side coding here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64166/discussion-between-ravi-and-sameera)

Comment: ` if(result){
         res.send{error: "REQUEST ALREADY EXISTS"};
 }`in here i get unexpected token?

Comment: @ravi and i run code with return statement ` return {error: "REQUEST ALREADY EXISTS"}` and my unique value as i get {serivice : service} but then server console says service notdefind